# Laravel find and replace content on the basis of a expression in content coming from Db

Tags: php, reactjs, regex, laravel, model-view-controller

I have a blog content in which admin can add  pattern like this => %make123%.
when that content is to be displayed i have to replace that %make123% with the vehicle id of 123 but now how to get that 123 from my content. and then make another query to search the vehicle with that id.

this is my controller function for blog detail.

```
function blogDetail($blog_id, $title_link){

$dataSetArray = array();
$dataSetArray['route'] = '/blog/:blog_title';

$rs = "SELECT id, post_title, post_meta_title, post_author, post_meta_description, 
post_meta_keywords, 
post_content, post_image, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%b-%Y') as created_at FROM blog_post
where id = '$blog_id' AND CONCAT( CONCAT( CONCAT( SUBSTRING(MY_TITLE(post_title), 1, 50),'-'), 
id),'.html') = '$title_link' ";
$results = DB::select($rs);





$results = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);
foreach ($results as $key => $value){
  $content =  $value['post_content'];
}

$pattern = '/%make(.+?)%/';

preg_match_all($pattern,$content,
$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);


}
```

Backend is in laravel and frontend is in react js.

Comment: Do you want to get 123 from %make123%?

Comment: yes @VPC want to get 123 but 123 is dynamic value. and then query on the basis of this id

Comment: Your `$out` should now holds an array of matches including submatches, which allows you to find the number 123. Than search your database for 123. And than perform a preg_replace replacing make123 with the contents from your database. Using laravel? Why not use eloquent models and their queries. Your foreach loop is also a bit odd, since it sets contents only for the last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to get your content id from the given string.

```
$regex = '/(%)([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)(%)/m';
    
preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    
// Print the entire match result
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0][3]);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks  your solution worked for me iam able to query the data on the basis of this id now can you tell me please  that  now i want to replace that whole %make123% with the new content. ?

Comment: @faizan preg_replace($regex, $change_value, $content);